# How do I make the background color fade into a different color after hovering it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to make the starter inputs for my text rpg change the background color in a fade effect with JQuery, but I cant figure out what i did wrong. Heres the part im focusing on:

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $Intro_Inputs = $('#Header_Intro input');
      $Intro_Inputs.hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({'background-color':'#2E8AE5'}, 'slow');
      }); 
    });
  </script>
```

If anyone could help me out with the mistake i made i would greatly appreciate it!

(The problem was that it wouldnt fade the colors in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) says:

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the [jQuery.Color plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) is used).

You can't do it with jQuery without the [jQuery.Color plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color).

Alternatively, you could do it with CSS without javascript:
`//animates to the hover state`
`#Header_Intro input:hover {
    background: #2E8AE5;
    transition: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -o-transition: 0.5s;
}`
`//animates to the normal state`
`#Header_Intro input {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    transition: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -o-transition: 0.5s;
}`

Comment: Oh, thanks :D
But how would i make the color fade back to normal after leaving the button area? Would i need to use the JQuery.Color plugin thing?

Comment: In CSS, simply add a transition to the normal color on the normal state.
With jQuery (and the jQuery Color plugin) you can supply a second function to hover() for the "hover to normal" transition.